# get minimum duration from self join table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm

Need some help on building query. I have a relation one to many between a `bookings` table and `booking_versions` table. each time bookings status change a new `booking_versions` row is generated in which `status` and `created_at` columns are specified. I'm targeting to get minimum duration between statuses statuses changes. Here what I've tried since now

```
def self.min( filter )
  query = <<-SQL
    SELECT bv1.item_id AS 'obj_id', MIN(
    bv2.created_at - bv1.created_at) AS 'mintime'
    FROM bus_booking_versions AS bv1
    INNER JOIN bus_booking_versions AS bv2
    ON bv1.item_id = bv2.item_id
    WHERE bv1.status = ?
    AND bv1.created_at >= ?
    AND bv1.created_at <= ?
    AND bv2.status IN (?)
    AND bv2.created_at >= ?
    AND bv2.created_at <= ?
  SQL
  self.find_by_sql([query, filter.start_status, filter.from_start, filter.to_start, filter.end_statuses, filter.from_end, filter.to_end])
end
```

That's rails code still it uses pure sql. This query does not work right. May be you could advise how to get bookings that where operated minimum time().

bus booking versions schema (item_id is a foreign key for booking)

```
  create_table "bus_booking_versions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "item_type",  limit: 255,        null: false
    t.integer  "item_id",    limit: 4,          null: false
    t.string   "event",      limit: 255,        null: false
    t.string   "whodunnit",  limit: 255
    t.text     "object",     limit: 4294967295
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.integer  "status",     limit: 4
  end
```

versions are created by paper tail gem in such way

```
has_paper_trail on: [:create, :update],
                class_name: "Bus::BookingVersion",
                meta: { status: Proc.new { |t| t.status if t.status_changed? } }
```

Comment: If you would add table structures and two-three sample data with expected output, it will be easy to help.

Comment: Tip: you can add tag of your DB, provide example of expected result, and there will be a chance you get answer from dba guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't know which database engine you're using, I'll write out a general SQL statement. Your DB engine of choice may have a better way of doing this.

Rather than joining the same table together (where you'll just be comparing identical rows, due to your `bv1.item_id = bv2.item_id`), you can use a subquery to get the "next" row in the table. Then you simply iterate over one instance of the table.

Specifically, a subquery like this, which finds the earliest created_at which is later than your current row's created_at (ie "the next row"), is what you'll want to compare:

`select min(created_at) from bus_booking_versions bv2 where bv1.item_id=bv2.item_id and created_at > bv1.created_at`

Here's the general query. I've used mysql's [timediff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) function, but you can change it to your particular DB engine's method for calculating datetime differences. Depending on your DB engine, there may be better ways to do this as well.

```
select
    bv1.item_id as 'obj_id',
    mintime = timediff
        ( 
            (
                select 
                    min(created_at) 
                from 
                    bus_booking_versions bv2 
                where 
                    bv1.item_id=bv2.item_id
                    and created_at > bv1.created_at
            ),
            bv1.created_at
        )
from
    #tmp1 bv1
where
    timediff((select min(created_at) from bus_booking_versions bv2 where bv1.item_id=bv2.item_id and created_at > bv1.created_at), bv1.created_at) > 0
    and timediff((select min(created_at) from bus_booking_versions bv2 where bv1.item_id=bv2.item_id and created_at > bv1.created_at), bv1.created_at) is not null
order by
    timediff
```

Hopefully it looks pretty straightforward. I've expanded the timediff/subquery in the select to make it clearer to understand what's going on. The timediff()s in the where clause are the exact same as in the select, except that they're compressed to one line. This is to weed out instances where two bus_booking_versions have the same created_at, or where the timestamp being compared is the final/only row (no later rows).

You can add in the rest of your where clause to check for your other parameters; I've just left them out to keep the query clear and understandable. You can chain in the `.first` method to your statement in ruby if you only want to return the first row.

Comment: that's it man/ thanks alot. Specially for detailed answering. this stuff works